# Почему присобачивают?

Tags: этимология

"Присобачить" — значит приделать, приладить кое-как. Но, интересно, при чем тут собака? Почему так говорят?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово просторечное, есть смысл искать его этимологию в таких же просторечных выражениях.Был, например, такой глагол - СОБАЧИТЬ- делать что-л. быстро, интенсивно, изо всех сил, работать не покладая рук: Проект собачить. Собачу каждый день до ночи. Поговорка "Устала, как собака"-отсюда. С другой приставкой - засобачивать: "Я там такие деньги засобачивал". Но есть и засобачить - интенсивно забросить.

http://slovarionline.ru/slovar_russkogo_argo/page/sobachit.11497

В словаре арго: http://slovarionline.ru/slovar_russkogo_argo/page/zasobachit.4258/

ЗАСОБАЧИВАТЬ (сов. ЗАСОБАЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь). 1. что куда. Забрасывать, закидывать, забивать; совершать любое интенсивное действие. 2. кого. Ругать, бранить кого-л.; принижать, унижать кого-л.

У Даля: "Собачить - шалить, дурить, пакостить, портить из шалости, бранить, ругать, поносить." Это тоже не расходится со значением "Делать что-то интенсивно"

Значит, ПРИСОБАЧИТЬ - приделать что-то грубо, интенсивно,испортив вещь, напакостив, как играющая собака что-то рвёт, шаля.

Answer (score 3):

Собаками, собачками, собачихами называли репьи - головки, соцветия репейника (он же - собачий репей).
http://dal.sci-lib.com/word036278.html

Присобачить(ся) - пристать как репей: некрасиво, неаккуратно, но крепко и надежно.

Answer (score 2):

Во дворе дома маленькая собачонка заливисто лает, бегает из угла в угол. Возможно, именно такая деятельность, которая не кажется нам достойной, правильной, разумной или интеллектуальной, лежит в основе нескольких просторечных глаголов на "собачью" тематику:

СОБАЧИТЬСЯ -  ругаться;
ЗАСОБАЧИТЬ - забросить неизвестно куда;
НАСОБАЧИТЬСЯ - научиться что-то делать после долгих повторов;
СОБАЧИТЬ - заниматься утомительной, интенсивной, нетворческой  работой;
ПРИСОБАЧИТЬ - что-то приделать, присоединить на скорую руку.

Comment: *Собачья жизнь, и термины - собачьи...*

Comment: По  правде  говоря,  только  "собачиться" - "ругаться",  "переругиваться" -  можно  легко  связать  с  собачьей  темой.  Есть  ещё  и  глагол  "лаяться"  в  этом  же  значении.  С  другими  словами  как-то  туманно  очень.  "Присобачить"  ближе  к  слову  "собачка" ( репей ) -  как-то  сам  цепляется.  "Отсобачить" - явно  от  "присобачить".  "Насобачиться" -  можно  связать  с  натаскиванием   охотничей  или  служебной  собаки.  А  "собачить"  -  заниматься  утомительной  и  нудной   работой  -  к  собаке   за  уши  притягивать  надо.

Comment: Думаю, что не надо в каждом случае искать смысловую связь глагола с конкретной собакой о четырех ногах. "Собачьи" глаголы могут привести нас к очень интересному языковому явлению. Дело в том, что основа СОБАЧ  в этих словах утрачивает конкретное предметное  значение и приобретает ОБОБЩЕННЫЙ НЕГАТИВНЫЙ СМЫСЛ. Вот, к примеру, глагол "собачить". Его настоящее смысловое значение мы без труда восстанавливаем из контекста (кстати, собачить - это еще и ругать, а не только работать), а сама основа передает только негативную оценку.

Comment: Так что ПРИСОБАЧИТЬ - это приделать, но осуществить это с помощью подручных средств,  "в полевых условиях".Что касается репейника, то  по своему характеру он очень напоминает маленькую злую собачонку, вцепившуюся в вашу одежду (может быть, отсюда следует его название).

Comment: Нет,  скорее  всего  его  приходилось  вытаскивать  из  шерсти  собак.

Comment: ИЗ ФОРУМНЫХ РАЗГОВОРОВ. Когда человека  обвиняют в чем-нибудь, можно услышать выражение: «На него вешают собак». эта фраза связана вовсе не с животным, а с другим значением слова «собака» - репей, колючка - теперь почти не употребляемым. Историк С. М. Соловьев  так отзывался о проф. П. М. Леонтьеве: «Цепкость была отличительным качеством Леонтьева: вцепится во что-нибудь - не отстанет; собака (`репейник') есть лучшее для него подобие».Собаками в просторечии называют репейник. До сих пор приехав в какую-нибудь дальнюю глухомань, можно услышать: "Ого, сколько собак на себя нацепляла".

Answer (score -1):

А почему все к собаке только присобачились ? Есть в слове ,,присобачить,, ещё одно легко узнаваемое слово - ,,бачить,, - ,,балабонить,, по Русски или  по Украински ,,видеть,, .. Логично предположить , что слово ,,присобачить,, означает , что то сделать легко , примерно как молоть языком или сделать только на словах - либо сделать что-то кое-как, только для вида .. Ну и собаку не забудем - сделать всё это ещё быстро , со злостью , азартом и собачьей хваткой (собачиться - ругаться) .. =)

Comment: ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ:ПРИСОБАЧИТЬ (груб. прост.) Прикрепить, приделать что-л. к чему-л. ПРИМЕР: "Атлас был необычайного формата, размером с газетный лист, и его никак не удавалось пристроить ни к багажнику, ни к раме [велосипеда]. Алеша решился было держать его всю дорогу под мышкой, но Васька предложил ему «присобачить» атлас на спину". Л. Соболев.
Значение слова явно просматривается: сделать какое-то временное крепление, при этом эмоции отсутствуют. И рассматривать "присобачить" отдельно от всей группы слов не имеет смысла, все они связаны общим значением, вот это значение и надо найти.

Comment: Прежде чем наши предки ввели в разговорную речь это шутливое выражение , думается , что возможно они и руководствовались именно теми соображениями которые я привёл .. Собака которая сидит на цепи и лает на любого прохожего со свойственным ей в этом положении кратковременным азартом  - делает это только для вида - работа такая .. Значение этого выражения надо искать не в единственном значении , а во множестве дополняющих друг друга значений .. =)

Comment: По ответу выше - дед Пателей никак не мог нажать собачку , он её мог только ,,спустить,, .. По вопросу ниже - почему курок называют ,,собачкой,, Спустить собаку (собачку) с поводка - что бы она цапнула обидчика и вернулась обратно к хозяину в исходную точку .. Думаю ,что смысл очевиден ..

Answer (score -1):

Боже мой, сколько шуму! Это обыкновенный сленг,родившийся во время оно и в любой привязке понятный. Вот,почему курок "собачкой" называют - вопрос. Тут есть,над чем извилинами пошевелить.Но можно спросить у Даля или в инете.

Comment: Курок  у  куркового  ружья  вполне  напоминает  собачью  голову - есть  и  мордочка  и  ушко.  Вот  почему  спусковой  крючок  собачкой  называют  -  вопрос ?

Comment: Речь шла не о значении слова (оно понятно), а о его происхождении (именно оно вызывает вопросы). К тому же сленг - это  неформальный (неофициальный)язык, на котором общаются определенные группы людей, а эти слова включены с отметкой "простор." в академические словари, да и трудно их отнести к какой-то группе.

Comment: Спусковой крючок напоминает собачий хвост - с. Не забываем и "собаку" : @.